# How to I add all of my mods to one profile in Minecraft (1.7.9) (Windows)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Basically I'm trying to do the Lucky Block Boss Challenge
(Check it out!

)
I need multiple mods to be able to do this (Single Player Commands, Lucky Block Mod)
But i have no clue how to add these mods into one Minecraft profile.
I've looked around for about two hours and all i've found was a Mac tut. and a Linux tut. that made my brain poop itself because i'm stupid lol. Oh, i am using 1.6.4 version of Minecraft for these mods.

Comment: Without doing any research at all, if I were you, I would check and see if these mods require forge, and if so, install forge, then drop the other mods into forge's mod folder because its really THAT easy. (after you install forge)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your request is the version history of the mods and the prerequisites for said mods.

You're running Minecraft 1.6.4, which the *Lucky Block Mod* has previous support for. You would need to download and install a capable version of *Minecraft Forge* which is available from their website.

However, you could not currently use *Single Player Commands* with that setup as support was dropped after the 1.6.2 update. It also requires a manual install directly into the `Minecraft.jar` file.

In short, you can't.